# Rails deployment to Heroku using Bulma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails application that I am trying to deploy to Heroku, but I am getting this error upon deployment:

```
Precompiling assets failed.
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma
```

I am using the following gem:

```
gem "bulma-rails", "~> 0.7.2"
```

I can't get it to work with Heroku. Has anyone had any experience doing this for deployment?

Comment: Do you have `@import "bulma";` in your application.scss? What happens when you run `bin/rails assets:precompile` do you get the same error?

Comment: @nzajt I do have it in my application.scss, and running bin/rails assets:precompile will generate the error 'Yarn executable was not detected in the system.'

Comment: Ok, so it look like you need to install yarn. Install yarn and then try it again. Here is the link to install yarn https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install